# How truncate file length in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, gnu-prolog, iso-prolog

How do I truncate the file length in Prolog?

I only find a `set_stream_position/2` predicate in the ISO 
standard. But I don't find a `set_stream_length/2` predicate 
in the major Prolog systems.

Similarly there is a stream property `position/1`, but I
don't see nowhere a `length/1` stream property. The latter
would help in using `set_stream_length/2`.

What would be the workaround?

Bye

Comment: Do you want `set_stream_length/2`? Why should this operation be of relevance for streams in general?

Comment: There are several issues here: `length` meaning number of bytes (C/Java) vs. characters; the validity of this operation (when it cuts part of a multi-octet character); and the fact that this only makes sense for files.

Comment: `set_stream_position/2` is well defined only, if you use a position obtained by `stream_property/2`. You cannot make any assumptions about it, except that it is a ground term and that it uniquely identifies a certain position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it !

see [this](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=set_end_of_stream/1) page...

*edit* after @false comment, here a sketch of encapsulating code:

```
set_file_size(Path, Size) :-
    setup_call_cleanup(
        open(Path, update, S),
        (   stream_property(S, reposition(true)),
            % stream_property(S, position(Q)),
            % set_stream_position(S, Q),
            seek(S, Size, bof, Size),
            set_end_of_stream(S)
        ),
        close(S)).
```

This works, but relies on [seek](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=seek/4)/4 builtin. I can't fully determine the status of such call WRT ISO compliance. It's listed under ISO IO, but untagged as compliant...

Those 2 commented lines served to me to inspect the *opaque* term position/1. There is a [stream_position_data](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=stream_position_data/3) to inquiry the values.

Comment: First seek and then set eof. Oki Doki.